# What are the hanging mushrooms for in the Super Adventure Box?

Tags: guild-wars-2

So in this months content 'Super Adventure Box' there are a number of jumping mushroom which are at an angle with a green glowing item hanging from them.

When attacked the green item falls to the ground and vanishes and the mushroom drops to being horizontal.

Do these have a use? My first guess was that they were for doing large horizontal jumps.

Ref: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Super_Adventure_Box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the [Joystiq guide to Super Adventure Box](http://massively.joystiq.com/2013/03/31/your-guide-to-guild-wars-2s-super-adventure-box/):

`If someone is [...]  having some serious issues getting to the checkpoint, look around near you for a mushroom sitting at an angle; shortcut mushrooms have been placed at strategic points along the map to help struggling groupmates catch up. Give it a tap and it should drop a little helper mushroom down to your buddy.`

The mushrooms that spawn underneath are the trampoline mushrooms that you can bounce on.